# How to use slidinguppanel in fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, adapter

I have 3 fragments and im trying to use the slidinguppanel from this library https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel.

But how can i use the same slidinguppanel across all fragments, so the content stays the same and i don't have to make another sliding up panel in the other layout?

**This is my xml for fragment 1**

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mSlideUpPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    tools:context=".fragments.Tab1"
    app:umanoPanelHeight="70dp"
    app:umanoShadowHeight="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".fragments.Tab1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSongs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/activity_song" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```